# Evaluating exponential function without overflow

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following function:
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{A} \cdot \frac{e^{\sqrt{A}x} + e^{\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{A}x}}{B\sqrt{A}e^{\sqrt{A}} - B\sqrt{A} + e^{\sqrt{A}} + 1}
$$

where $A = 10^{6}$ and $B = 10^{-7}$. I am attempting to do several calculations and visualizations of $f$ for $x \in [0,1]$. I obviously get overflow errors due to the presence of $e^{\sqrt{A}}$ and $e^{\sqrt{A}x}$, but I know for a fact that $f$ is bounded in the region I am evaluating it in. I tried to fix this by doing the following manipulation:
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^{\sqrt{A}x - \sqrt{A}}}{A} \cdot \frac{1 + e^{\sqrt{A} - 2\sqrt{A}x}}{B\sqrt{A} - B\sqrt{A}e^{-\sqrt{A}} + 1 + e^{-\sqrt{A}}}.
$$

But the issue is that for small $x$, $e^{\sqrt{A} - 2\sqrt{A}x}$ still overflows. So I'm wondering is there some clever manipulation I could do that allows me to fully evaluate $f$ in the desired region?

Answer (score 1):

The numerator may be written as $$e^{\sqrt{A}(x-1/2)}e^{\sqrt{A}/2} + e^{-\sqrt{A}(x-1/2)}e^{\sqrt{A}/2} = 2 e^{\sqrt{A}/2} \cosh ((x-1/2) \sqrt{A}).$$  The denominator may be written as
$$2 A e^{\sqrt{A}/2} ( B \sqrt{A} \sinh \sqrt{A}/2 + \cosh \sqrt{A}/2).$$  Cancellation yields $$f(x) = \frac{\cosh ((x-1/2)\sqrt{A})}{A (B \sqrt{A} \sinh \sqrt{A}/2 + \cosh \sqrt{A}/2)}.$$  We are further inspired to employ a hyperbolic trigonometric angle addition identity:  $$\cosh(w+z) = \sinh w \sinh z + \cosh w \cosh z$$ with the choice $w = \cosh^{-1} (1- B^2 A)^{-1/2}$ and $z = \sqrt{A}/2$ gives $$f(x) = \frac{\cosh((x - 1/2) \sqrt{A})}{A \sqrt{1 - B^2 A} \cosh (w + \sqrt{A}/2)}.$$  From here we take logarithms to obtain $$\log f(x) = \log \cosh ((x - 1/2) \sqrt{A}/2) - \log \cosh (w + \sqrt{A}/2) - \log A \sqrt{1 - B^2 A}.$$  The last term is a fixed constant, and for your choice of $A, B$, is well within machine precision to compute.

The second term is, to a high degree of precision, approximately equal to $w + \frac{\sqrt{A}}{2} - \log 2$, since for sufficiently large $z$, $$\log \cosh z = \log \frac{e^{z} + e^{-z}}{2} \approx z - \log 2.$$  Again, for your choice of $A, B$, this is tractable.

The only thing remaining is computing the first term.  If your overflow limit is on the order of $e^M$, where $M$ is your largest exponent your computation's floating point arithmetic can handle, then when $$|x - 1/2| \sqrt{A} \ge M,$$ you want to use the approximation above; i.e., $$\log \cosh ((x-1/2) \sqrt{A}) \approx \left|x - \frac{1}{2}\right|\sqrt{A} - \log 2.$$  If there is no overflow, then you simply evaluate the function as is.

Answer (score 0):

When $x$ is small, use Taylor
$$e^{\sqrt{A} (x-1)}=e^{-\sqrt{A}}\left(1+\sqrt{A} x+\frac{A }{2}x^2+O\left(x^3\right) \right)$$